# Google Trends weekly data

Tags: data-request, extracting, trends

I have an issue regarding google trends: I have noticed that recently something has changed.

I used to be able to get all my weekly-based data, no matter the time period I was interested in. A couple of days ago I have realized that this is no longer possible: google trends lets me see and download the weekly-based data only if I'm analyzing a time period of maximum 5 years.

If I'm dealing with a 6 years period, for example, I can still download my data, but it is only monthy-based.

Do you know if there s any solution to this?

Comment: I've exactly the same problem and it seems there is no solution. I've read some people suggest having an overlapping week, so that we can rescale one of the 2 time series. However, this does not work because the proportion between the 2 time series is not constant, i.e. if we have 2 overlapping weeks, we see there is no constant rescaling term (the issue is worse as we increase overlapping weeks).

Comment: How this question relates to OPEN data?

Comment: pytrends' api offers search by time https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. 
I tried to split the time span and download data for two five year time spans with three years overlap. However, rescaling doesn't work. The patterns of the data points is different

[image]

However, if you are interested in a few queries only, google correlate might be work around. Here you can still download weekly data. Try:

1. Download a <5 year time span for your query from google trends
2. Upload the data in google correlate (this can be a bit tricky though) and hope that google finds a perfect correlation with the query you are looking for
3. download data for 10 years+

Comment: That link is dead. Please fix it.